# How to create new array from existing or reverse order of lists Python

Tags: python, arrays, switch-statement

I have 2 lists in an array.  I would like to switch the list order. list 2 becomes list 1, and list one becomes list 2. I'd appreaciet some help on how to efficiently switch these. Thanks

I have the following code in python.

```
RestoredData_Array = np.dot(featuresT.reshape(2,2), FinalData1_Matrix.reshape(2,20))
RestoredData_Array
```

Actual Results:

```
array([[  2.3065    ,   9.21202097,   2.03334271,   8.12104732,
          1.02492108,   4.09347257,  -0.54700703,  -2.18471288,
          0.15896622,   0.63490144,  -0.51904295,  -2.07302602,
         -2.11190708,  -8.43482867,  -3.33826623, -13.33283264,
         -3.24268925, -12.95110399,  -3.39616989, -13.56409637],

       [ -9.93383348, -39.6751278 , -11.51169937, -45.9770284 ,
        -13.27291919, -53.01123343, -12.73236969, -50.85231155,
        -13.35424863, -53.33605825, -14.86736232, -59.37934246,
        -17.41605181, -69.55865355, -17.84717309, -71.28052577,
        -19.07951685, -76.20243193, -20.72810021, -82.78677378]])
```

Desired Results:

```
array([[ -9.93383348, -39.6751278 , -11.51169937, -45.9770284 ,
        -13.27291919, -53.01123343, -12.73236969, -50.85231155,
        -13.35424863, -53.33605825, -14.86736232, -59.37934246,
        -17.41605181, -69.55865355, -17.84717309, -71.28052577,
        -19.07951685, -76.20243193, -20.72810021, -82.78677378]

        [  2.3065    ,   9.21202097,   2.03334271,   8.12104732,
          1.02492108,   4.09347257,  -0.54700703,  -2.18471288,
          0.15896622,   0.63490144,  -0.51904295,  -2.07302602,
         -2.11190708,  -8.43482867,  -3.33826623, -13.33283264,
         -3.24268925, -12.95110399,  -3.39616989, -13.56409637]])
```

Comment: RestoredData_Array[::-1]

Comment: You should accept an answer if it solved your issue. Otherwise the question remains in the queue for more answers. Also, if you find an answer helpful you should upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like all you want is to change `[a, b]` to `[b, a]` where `a` and `b` are your lists.

There are many ways. The code below is the shortest and it works with both lists and numpy arrays.

```
Reversed_Array = RestoredData_Array[::-1]
```

This is the slicing trick. See [here](https://dbader.org/blog/python-reverse-list) to understand how this works.

Comment: Thanks. This worked.  Appreciate your help!

Comment: @sunnyspain1 Good to know. Just so you're aware: if you find an answer helpful you should upvote it instead of writing a comment. That way others know which answers are good.

Answer (score 0):

Interchanging the value of two arrays:

```
a=[1]
b=[2]
a,b = b,a
print(a)
print(b)
```

Interchanging the value of nested array:

```
c=[[1],[2]] # here c[0] have value [1] & c[1] have value [2] 
c[0],c[1] = c[1],c[0] # here we are interchanging the value of c[0] & c[1]
print(c)
```

These examples may help you to transform your array

For your code this may work:

```
RestoredData_Array = np.dot(featuresT.reshape(2,2), FinalData1_Matrix.reshape(2,20))
RestoredData_Array[0],RestoredData_Array[1] = RestoredData_Array[1],RestoredData_Array[0]
print(RestoredData_Array)
```